# How to disable list of dates in MUI date picker

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to disable MUI date picker future dates (only selected dates not all future dates)
I am getting array of dates from API which needs to be disabled from date picker.

Assume that below **blackoutDates** are what i am getting from API. So how to disable those dates ?

Below is my code

```
const getDisabledDates = () => {
 let blackoutDates = {[
    "2022-03-01",
    "2022-03-08"
    "2022-04-13",
    "2022-05-22"
 ]}
}
```

```
<DatePicker
  disablePast
  value={checkout.rideDate}
  shouldDisableDate={getDisabledDates}
  onChange={(newValue) => {
   dispatch(setRideDate(newValue?.toISOString().split('T')[0]))
   }}
  renderInput={(params) => <TextField  className={classes.datePickerStyle} {...params}/>}
/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`shouldDisableDate` is a function with the current date in param. So you need to compare this with your array, to enable / disable the date

```
const shouldDisableDate= date => {
  let blackoutDates = {[
    "2022-03-01",
    "2022-03-08"
    "2022-04-13",
    "2022-05-22"
  ]}

  return blackoutDates.includes(date);
}
```

This is an exemple, as your `date` is of type `Date` whereas your array contains strings. So you'll need to convert the `date` to a `YYYY-MM-DD` string first, using your prefered way :)

Comment: Thanks dude it worked for me.                                                                                                          return blackoutDates.includes(date.toISOString().split('T')[0]);

Answer (score 0):

Handler prop `shouldDisableDate` passes a date argument to the function you provide. So, your function could look like:

```
const getDisabledDates = (date) => {
 let blackoutDates = [
    "2022-03-01",
    "2022-03-08"
    "2022-04-13",
    "2022-05-22"
 ];
 // check `date` object against blackoutDates.
 // return true | false 
}
```

Keep in mind that the date parameter is a vanilla Date object.
More info at [MUI documentation](https://mui.com/components/date-picker/#landscape-orientation). In the example, you can see how a function `isWeekend` is passed to a prop `shouldDisableDate`. According to [date-fns](https://date-fns.org/v2.28.0/docs/isWeekend#arguments) documentation this function accepts the date object. I suggest You play around in the demo that MUI provides.